# Vertically center items in a view

Tags: javascript, css, react-native

I need to center all these items in the center of the screen, however, when using `justifyContent: "center"` nothing happens.

I removed some of the code that I deemed unnecessary. If so, just say that I will post it completely:

[image: Problem]

**Environment**

- react-native: 0.60
- Device: Samsung S8+

**Code**

```
      <View>
        <Header style={{ backgroundColor: '#006bb3' }}>
          <Left>
            <Icon
              name="arrow-left" type='MaterialCommunityIcons'
              style={{ color: "#FFF" }}
              onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('HomeLogin')} />
          </Left>
          <Body>
            <Title style={{color:'#FFF'}}>Entrar</Title>
          </Body>
          <Right />
        </Header>
      </View>
      <View style={styles.container }>
        <Image source={require('../assets/logo.png')} style={{width: 284, height: 76, marginBottom: 78}} />
        <TextInput 
          placeholder="E-Mail"
          style={styles.input}
        />
       <TouchableOpacity style={styles.btn} activeOpacity={0.8}>
          <LinearGradient start={{x: 0, y: 0}} end={{x: 1, y: 0}} style={styles.btn} colors={['#1aa3ff', '#006bb3']}>
            <Text style={styles.textbtn}>
              Entrar
            </Text>
          </LinearGradient>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
      </View>
```

Styles:

```
import { StyleSheet, Dimensions } from 'react-native';
  container: {
    alignItems:'center',
    justifyContent:"center"  
  },
```

I would like the content to be centered vertically on the device screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem! I defined a view with 100% available height and used justify content to center

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```
 container: {
    flex:1
    alignItems:'center',
    justifyContent:'center'  
  },
```

Comment: When i use justify my image just disappears. Thanks for your help